# How to change limit open file of root user , on Centos 6.4 x64

Tags: limit, centos6, limits, ulimit

I tried several way to change open file limit from URL

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

which I have changed limit.conf and  /etc/sysctl.conf

it work with other user , but limit open file of root doesn't changed

## /etc/security/limits.conf

```
#####
*       -        nproc           8500
*       hard     nofile          200000
*       soft     nofile          200000
*       hard     stack           8192
*       hard    sigpending       45056

root    hard     nofile          200000
root    soft     nofile          200000
root    hard     no file         200000
```

## /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
fs.file-max = 200000
```

Reboot server , After that

```
[root@ironman ~]# ulimit -n
8192
```

Finally I add command below on /etc/bashrc and it works for root user as well
I really don't understand why setting only on sysctl.conf /limits.conf doesn't affect ?

Please advise

Comment: new settings added to sysct.conf will not take effect immediately until the next time you boot your machine.

Comment: I already reboot machine , still not affect

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ulimit -n 200000` into `/etc/sysconfig/init` file and reboot.